# Verifying how the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}$ works

Tags: notation

I'm a little bit confused. This is a very easy question but I'm solving lots of exercises and I want to be crystal clear about that.

I want to verify how this sum works.

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}$$

Let's take $n=2$. So we will have 
$$(-1)^0\binom{2}{0}+(-1)^1\binom{2}{1}+(-1)^2\binom{2}{2}=2-2=0$$
Is that true ?

Thank you

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I've formatted the mathematics for you. Please check that I have accurately captured your intent. (I took the liberty of changing the exponent on $(-1)$ from "$r$" to "$k$".)

Comment: What do you mean other way around?

Comment: You have successfully unpacked the summation, and the answer is correct. (I don't know what you mean by "other way around".) Were I having someone check my work, I might have added a step evaluating each term explicitly: "$(1)\cdot(1)+(-1)\cdot(2)+(1)\cdot(1)$". Had the final answer been incorrect, this would have helped in identifying, say, a minor arithmetic error.

Comment: I mean in 'other way around' if I made an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hints:**

Find the expansion of $\left(1-x\right)^n$ and substitute $x=1$

**Spoiler:**

> $\quad\left(1-x\right)^n \\ = \sum_{k=0}^n \begin{pmatrix} n\\k \end{pmatrix}1^{n-k}\left(-x\right)^k \\ =\sum_{k=0}^n \left(-1\right)^k x^k\begin{pmatrix} n\\k \end{pmatrix}\\ \text{Substitute both side by $x=1$ and we get}\\ \left(1-1\right)^n=0=\sum_{k=0}^n \left(-1\right)^k\begin{pmatrix} n\\ k \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I've got a question to this solution about one step. I'm interested in the second step where from 1^(n-k)(-x)^k we get (-1)^kx^k

Comment: I've been trying to solve this. Begin with 1^(n-k)(-x)^k=1^n/1^k(-x)^k=1^n*(-x)^k and what is the next step

Comment: Obviously, $1^k=1$ for any constant $k$ @MichałWaligóra

Comment: @MichałWaligóra then by using $\left(ab\right)^n=a^n b^n$, we get $\left(-x\right)^k=\left(-1\right)^kx^k$

Comment: Thank you very much